# Compare 2 XML files using just C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm looking for a way to compare to XML files (examples below) and create a list containing the xpath to the differences in the two files so I can then check what has changed.

can this be done in Linq or will I need to use MS Diff patch, I would really like to do it all in C# without any additional Dlls.

Or should I just loop trough one XML file and compare it to the other, but then if I do this I may miss any new or deleted nodes!

File A

```
<info>
  <Retrieve>
    <LastNameInfo>
      <LNameNum>1</LNameNum>
      <NumPeople>1</NumPeople>
      <NameType/>
      <LName>TEST</LName>
    </LastNameInfo>
    <Segment>
      <SegNum>1</SegNum>
      <Comment>A test</Comment>
    </Segment>
    <Segment>
      <SegNum>2</SegNum>
      <Dt>20110910</Dt>
      <Comment>B test</Comment>
    </Segment>
  </Retrieve>
</info>
```

File B:

```
    <info>
  <Retrieve>
    <LastNameInfo>
      <LNameNum>1</LNameNum>
      <NameType/>
      <LName>TESTING</LName>
    </LastNameInfo>
    <Segment>
      <SegNum>1</SegNum>
      <Status>HS</Status>
      <Comment>A test</Comment>
    </Segment>
    <Segment>
      <SegNum>2</SegNum>
      <Dt>20110910</Dt>
      <Comment>COULD I USE LINQ</Comment>
    </Segment>
  </Retrieve>
</info>
```

Output XPath list

```
/info/Retrieve/LastNameInfo/NumPeople
/info/Retrieve/LastNameInfo/LName
/info/Retrieve/Segment[1]/Status
/info/Retrieve/Segment[2]/Comment
```

Comment: Please provide the wanted output for the above example files.

Comment: Are we to assume that the XML structure must match between the two files?

Comment: Updated the Q with the Xpath List I'm looking generate as the output.

i would then in code examine each Xpath in for each document and decide which to keep or to merge the result...

Comment: The structure will match if the elements are there they will be in the same place but for example there could be up to 9 Segments sections or none!

Comment: @Adrian only you know what variation you expect. In cases where there are constraints on how much the files can vary it's possible to get limited solutions. But the general quesions is similar to comparing text files

Comment: @Peter thanks the problem I'm having is that I know what elements to compare and the nodes may have additional section in some files then others. so I need way of identifying not only the difference between the structures and the elements data!

I think I'm confusing myself!

I thought if I can get a list of with the xpath to all the differences I could then step through that to work out what has changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to compare the equivalence of the XML (the Infoset) and not just the lexical equivalence of the files. XML can vary significantly in its lexical form (choice of quoting, insiginficant whitespace, order of attributes). All these can be varied without affecting the infoset.

I would canonicalize the files 
[XML Canonicalization algorithm gives two difference results when called directly than when called as part of an xml digital signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026432/xml-canonicalization-algorithm-gives-two-difference-results-when-called-directly)
and test for lexical identity. If they are not equivalent it can be quite difficult to determine where they differ (trivial differences are relatively easy, but when element order, etc. is important there may be no objective difference.

I have done this for my own app (in Java, sorry) and it wasn't trivial - and again I assumed a fairly close equivalence between the files. I also made it work for real numbers which had to agree within epsilon where lexical equivalence isn't good enough.

see [Xml Comparison in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794331/xml-comparison-in-c) for some XMLDiff tools

Comment: I'd be intrigued if you're aware of even an external tool to do such a thing?

Comment: Here is MS XMLDiff and patch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx - this page shows the different things that have to be taken into account

Comment: Hi yes its the Infoset i wish to compare, the files will always be different as it contains time stamps etc but its the node contents I want to compare.