# how to compare two xml values and print the difference between two in c#

Tags: c#, xml, compare

I want to compare two xml documents.Both documents have some similarities and dissimilarities.I want to note down the difference between the two documents separately.Is there any C# function to separate the difference between the two xml document or any other way to do it.Please suggest me some solution.
Thanks In advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660971/compare-2-xml-files-using-just-c-sharp

Comment: or duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794331/xml-comparison-in-c-sharp

Comment: what do you mean about "two values"? what are the values? and these are value of what?