# Fail to re-write valid digital signature using dom

Tags: java, xml, dom, digital-signature

I have an XML where one part is signed with a digital signature. The signature is has been added "enveloped". Now I need to read the xml using DOM, change some UNSIGNED parts and write the DOM to XML again (the signed part of the DOM and the Signature is left unchanged).
Unfortunately, when I verify the signature after write to xml, it reports a failed signature.
I compared the two documents (before change and after change). The difference is in the line-wrapping of the signature info. The valid document does not have line wrapping in the signature info:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2"><XPath xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">/LicensePool/License</XPath></Transform><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>jLCnv/w4jErO3lQGgHrQSNC5Q2jczGXBfbBHTSemulA=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>(...skipped...)</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>(...skipped...)</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue></KeyInfo></Signature>
```

, while the changed, invalid one wraps lines after any closing tag.

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
<XPath xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">/LicensePool/License</XPath>
</Transform>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>jLCnv/w4jErO3lQGgHrQSNC5Q2jczGXBfbBHTSemulA=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>(...skipped...)</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>(...skipped...)</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

The code which writes the DOM to XML does not "know" about the signature and it's transformation stuff. It is just a component which can read, edit and write XML/DOM. It writes the DOM as follows:

```
private void saveXml() throws TransformerException, IOException {
  try(OutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))){
    Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
    Result result = new StreamResult(fos);
    TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformer.transform(source, result);
  }
}
```

For the verification of the xml-signature after write, I use the Java Xml digital signature API.
Any Idea what's going wrong?

Comment: did you try to add `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");` to prevent the line wrapping?

Comment: @wero: thanks for the hint. Setting INDENT to "no" helps. Unfortunately, this  then applies to the whole xml of course, which is not what I wanted, But as a workaround it will do. 
Related to this, I found the following question [XML Canonicalization algorithm gives two difference results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026432/xml-canonicalization-algorithm-gives-two-difference-results-when-called-directly?rq=1) which   has a similar cause. Namely that the xml signature verification algorithm seems to be sensitive for whitespaces, which "right-thinking people" would not expect.